# Example of the infinite point density of continua

Tags: geometry, infinity

There is an interesting example that I've seen, possibly attributed to Hilbert.  One draws a ray from the center of a circle to every point in the circle, and then one increases the radius of the circle to expose gaps between the rays.  In general, this has to do with the cardinality of infinite sets.  I am unable to locate this classical example via Google.  Can tell me the name of this example, or link me to some material that discusses it.  I want to be sure that it was Hilbert's demonstration, and I want to be sure that I'm getting everything from that was originally intended.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure? "Increases the radius of the circle to expose gaps between the rays"? There are no gaps between rays. Distances between points on the rays do grow, but this has nothing to do with cardinality: intervals of any length are of the same cardinality.

Comment: @Conifold Thank you for this point of semantics that you raised, now I have more knowledge.  Can you please make a comment pertaining to the request in the post?

Comment: The demonstration, as you describe it, did not happen, especially one associated with Hilbert. But try to remember if it was actually related to cardinality or perhaps something else, that might help figure out what it is that you think you remember.